# Linearity of electrochemical cells and electrical conductivity measurement

Tags: electrochemistry, conductivity

I've measured the output signal of a few commercially available conductivity meters and was surprised to see that the signal was typically a square wave of amplitude in the range of 1.5 to 6 Vpp (peak-to-peak) and a frequency ranging from 4 to 20 kHz. One of the meters even had a dc (direct current) offset of about 200 mV.

My understanding is that for an electrochemical cell to behave as a linear system, and to avoid creating harmonic distortions, we typically use a sine-wave of around 10 mVrms (root-mean-square), but not much higher.

So, I'm a bit surprised with the characteristics of these meters.
Does anyone have an explanation for these meter characteristics? Mainly:

- Why they use amplitudes higher than 10 mVrms?
- Why the square wave instead of a sine wave?
- Why this variability in the used frequency and how can one possibly determine the correct value to use?
- What could explain the use of a dc offset although we know it could change the properties of our cell!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you describe may be the standard design, but it would be interesting (but is not absolutely necessary) to know what quality of meter, maybe the brand.

Comment: @BuckThorn, Not sure this helps but I've tested one meter from Walchem and two different meters from Hanna Instruments and another no-brand cheap one. Interestingly this latter only sends a single period of a 20 kHz square wave repeating every 60 ms and it gives quite different readings whereas for the rest the readings tend to be similar.

Comment: @BuckThorn, What would you say is the best approach to use if you want to measure electrical conductivity of water using two solid metalic electrodes (e.g., platinum, hastelloy, stainless steel, etc.)? What would be the appropriate signal to send across the electrodes and how would one go about exploiting the measured signal across the electrodes to get conductivity values?

Comment: If you want to make your own device I would think you can't do worse than attempting to duplicate what a commercial device does, provided it is of the desired quality. These instruments are usually calibrated, which may circumvent some of the biases. If you have a highly specialized application you may want to search the literature, for instance for high precision conductivity meters, or make your question here more focused so it is clear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: You may also want to look into impedance spectroscopy, for instance: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317622367_Electric_impedance_of_aqueous_KCl_and_NaCl_solutions_Salt_concentration_dependence_on_components_of_the_equivalent_electric_circuit